# Pass variable with subvariable from JQuery to Flask app

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, flask, wtforms

I have a Flask that uses WTForms and Jquery to take from the user "input" fields in a form and shows "select" fields to the user. Jquery is used to filter the select fields shown to the user based on what they enter in the input fields. In order to filter the select fields, I need to take what the user enters in the input fields and send it to the Flask app.

These are the form fields -

```
class TableName(FlaskForm):
    schema = StringField('Schema', validators=[DataRequired()], id = 'schema_name')
    table = StringField('Table', validators=[DataRequired()], id = 'table_name')


class QaForm(FlaskForm):
    test_table_in = FormField(TableName, id = 'test_table') 
    prod_table_in = FormField(TableName, id = 'prod_table')
```

This is the JQuery -

```
$(function() {
            var tables = {
                test_table: $('test_table_in-schema_name').val() + "." + $('test_table_in-table_name').val(),
                prod_table: $('prod_table_in-schema_name').val() + "." + $('prod_table_in-table_name').val()
            };

            var fields = {
                test: [$('#select_test_join_key'), $('#select_test_dimensions')],
                prod: [$('#select_prod_join_key'), $('#select_prod_dimensions')]
            };

            fields.test.forEach(item => updateFields(tables.test_table, item));
            fields.prod.forEach(item => updateFields(tables.prod_table, item));

            function updateFields(table, field) {
                var send = {
                    table: tables.table
                };

                $.getJSON("{{url_for('_get_fields') }}", send, function(data) {
                    //do something
                });
            }
            
         });
```

When the user enters a "test_table", the test table should get passed to _get_fields() and when the user enters a prod_table, that value should get sent to _get_fields(). Test_table and prod_table are two form fields, each consisting of two subfields, "schema" and "table" that are combined to create one field in the format "schema.table".

Function _get_fields() in Flask view to receive the table name -

```
@app.route('/_get_fields/')
def _get_fields():
    table = request.args.get('table', type=str)
    fields_query = f"""select column_name AS Fields from information_schema.columns WHERE 
                                table_name = '{table}' group by 1 limit 10;"""
    conn.execute(fields_query)
    result = conn.fetchall()
    return jsonify(result)
```

**Potential errors:**
It's the request_args.get() function in the Flask view that I believe is not referring correctly to the JQuery variables. I've tried 'test_table', 'prod_table', and others but none of these have worked so far. I'm using the "name" of the input form elements to create the table variables - I'm wondering if that may be a part of the issue as well. Any thoughts or suggestions?

Comment: don't you get error message ? You have wrong indentation in `def _get_fields()` and you should get error message.

Comment: did you check if you have error message in JavaScript's console in DevTools in web browser?  Maybe use `log.console()` to display what you get in variable because it seems you use wrong variables. Maybe you should use `table: table` instead of `table: tables.table`

Comment: @furas Sorry, that was my mistake in copying over the code but the actual code doesn't have this error. Fixed it above as well.

Comment: @furas, I do get an error saying "uncaught type error: tables.test_table.on is not a function". However, it was working just fine when I hard coded the value for "table" in the Flask method _get_fields(). So I'm not sure why it's not recognizing tables.test_table_on as soon as I change what I pass to the Flask method.

Comment: I don't understand what you say. Where do you get error - in browser or in Flask? JavaScript object and Flask object are different objects. And Flask get all as string, not as objects with functions.

Comment: @furas, the issue is basically that the Flask view is not picking up the 'send' variable that is being sent from JQuery. In JQuery updateFields function, I'm defining the 'send' variable as 'table' and send this to the Flask function _get_fields(). get_fields() should take this variable and use it to run a query. The problem is it's not taking this variable. Any thoughts?

Comment: @furas, Is it possible that in JQuery function, the test_table and prod_table are not defined correctly? I'm trying to use the "name" rather than "id" of the form fields because it is more specific.

Comment: I think that variables are correctly defined by you messed up with variables in function `updateFields()`. Variables have similar names and it can makes problem. In `forEach` you runs `updateFields(tables.test_table, ...` which assigns `tables.test_table` to variable local variable `tables` in  `send = {table: tables.table, ... }` and  external `tables` doesn't have `.table`  but `.test_table`. But you should rather use local variable `table` like `send = {table: table}` . All this because you use variables with similar names.

Comment: @furas, I tried to print the test_table and prod_table right after defining them at the top to the console in browser and I'm getting an "undefined.undefned" error so my guess is that those are not defined correctly. I'm using the html ID's that I assigned to the fields. Is there something wrong with how I'm selecting them in the JQuery?

Comment: as I remeber for ID you should start name with `#` - like in CSS - `$('#test_table_in-schema_name')` but it seems you forgot `#`